# Extract all transaction that must contains two or more items

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to extract from Redshift using SQL for transactions that contain certain items

| Customer id | Transaction id | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Apple |
| 1 | a | Pencil |
| 2 | b | Apple |
| 3 | c | Paper |
| 3 | c | Apple |
| 3 | e | Pencil |
| 4 | f | Apple |
| 5 | g | Apple |
| 5 | g | Paper |
|  | h | Apple |
|  | h | Pencil |
|  | h | Apple |
|  | h | Paper |
|  | i | Pencil |
|  | j | Paper |

How to extract all transactions containing Apple AND Pencil?

| Customer id | Transaction id | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Apple |
| 1 | a | Pencil |
|  | h | Apple |
|  | h | Pencil |
|  | h | Apple |
|  | h | Paper |

Comment: Will the Item column ever contain values other than Pencil or Apple? Will Apple or Paper ever be duplicated for the same Transaction id? Are you only wanting to find rows where Apple and Pencil appears **for the same Transaction id**, or is it only where they have the **same Customer id _AND_ the same Transaction id**?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein If you check the expected output, the aggregation seems to be by transaction ID only.

Comment: I have edited my table and expected result

Answer (score 0):

We could use a join aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT t1.CustomerId, t1.TransactionId, t1.Item
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TransactionId
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Item IN ('Apple', 'Pencil')
    GROUP BY TransactionId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Item) = 2
) t2
    ON t2.TransactionId = t1.TransactionId;
```

Comment: Nice! Would you say that using an INNER JOIN is more efficient than using a WHERE IN?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We can't really know the answer to this question without seeing the execution plans for both versions.  It could be the same plan for join and where in.